# Do boolean attributes require quotes in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, boolean

In ASP.NET markup do boolean attributes require quotes?

```
<asp:tag name="myTagName" IsEnabled=true />
```

or

```
<asp:tag name="myTagName" IsEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most common to use quotes, although the ASP.NET page parser doesn't require nor enforce this.

All 3 buttons below will be disabled, using double quotes, single quotes and no quotes to set the value of the `Enabled` property.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button1" Enabled="false" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button2" Enabled='false' />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button3" Enabled=false />
```

---

Only when an invalid mixed format is being used like here below,

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button4" Enabled="false' />
```

being a combination of double and single quotes, Visual Studio shows a warning/error feedback, mentioning that the quotation marks must match in case they are being applied.
The message doesn't state that quotation marks must be used.

> Validation (ASP.Net): If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.

[image]

At runtime the page will then fail with the error below.

> **Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message**: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Because these tags are in XML format and passing data should be in quotes,

[XML Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)

## Edit:

In IBM Website they have this example:

#### Incorrect

```
<?xml version= “1.0” encoding=“ISO-8859-1”?>
<note date=05/05/05>
<to>Dick</to>
<from>Jane</from>
</note>
```

#### Correct

```
<?xml version= “1.0” encoding=“ISO-8859-1”?>
<note date=”05/05/05”>
<to>Dick</to>
<from>Jane</from>
</note>
```

[source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRJDU/reference/SCN_XML_Syntax_Rules.html)